# Remove Gitlab EE from Centos7

Tags: centos7, gitlab, uninstall

I just installed https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#centos on Centos7 vps running Apache.  I should have read more before doing so as it conflicts with Apache and I don't want the EE edition.  How should I remove it?

```
curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
sudo yum install gitlab-ee
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

I tried the following.

```
sudo gitlab-ctl stop
sudo gitlab-ctl uninstall
rpm -e gitlab
```

And after rebooting, am far from uninstalled

```
[michael@vps~]$ ps -ef | grep gitlab
root       730     1  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 runsvdir -P /opt/gitlab/service log: ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
root       743   730  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 runsv gitlab-workhorse
root       750   730  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 runsv gitlab-monitor
root       751   743  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse
root       752   741  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq
git        753   743  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitlab-workhorse -listenNetwork unix -listenUmask 0 -listenAddr /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket -authBackend http://localhost:8080 -authSocket /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket -documentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public -pprofListenAddr  -secretPath /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.gitlab_workhorse_secret -config config.toml
git        754   741 21 13:49 ?        00:00:15 sidekiq 5.0.0 gitlab-rails [0 of 25 busy]
root       755   739  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/postgresql
root       756   738  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/redis
gitlab-+   757   739  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/postgres -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data
gitlab-+   758   738  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:0
root       759   740  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/unicorn
git        760   740  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitlab-unicorn-wrapper
root       761   749  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/postgres-exporter
gitlab-+   762   749  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/postgres_exporter -web.listen-address=localhost:9187
root       763   742  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/gitaly
git        764   742  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitaly /var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/config.toml
root       765   744  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/nginx
root       766   744  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -p /var/opt/gitlab/nginx
root       767   745  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/logrotate
root       768   750  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-monitor
root       769   745  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitlab-logrotate-wrapper
git        770   750  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitlab-mon web -c /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-monitor/gitlab-monitor.yml
root       771   746  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/prometheus
gitlab-+   772   746  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/prometheus -web.listen-address=localhost:9090 -storage.local.path=/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data -storage.local.chunk-encoding-version=2 -storage.local.target-heap-size=68005724 -config.file=/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/prometheus.yml
root       773   748  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/redis-exporter
gitlab-+   774   748  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/redis_exporter -web.listen-address=localhost:9121 -redis.addr=unix:///var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.socket
root       780   747  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/node-exporter
gitlab-+   781   747  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/node_exporter -web.listen-address=localhost:9100 -collector.textfile.directory=/var/opt/gitlab/node-exporter/textfile_collector
gitlab-+   832   766  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
gitlab-+   833   766  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
gitlab-+   834   766  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
gitlab-+   843   757  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process
gitlab-+   844   757  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process
gitlab-+   845   757  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process
gitlab-+   846   757  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
gitlab-+   847   757  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process
git        939     1 20 13:49 ?        00:00:14 unicorn master -D -E production -c /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config.ru
gitlab-+   997   757  0 13:49 ?        00:00:00 postgres: gitlab-psql postgres [local] idle
git       2631   939  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 unicorn worker[0] -D -E production -c /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config.ru
git       2634   939  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 unicorn worker[1] -D -E production -c /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config.ru
git       2639   939  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 unicorn worker[2] -D -E production -c /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config.ru
gitlab-+  2685   757  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+  2764   757  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+  2765   757  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+  2766   757  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+  2767   757  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+  2768   757  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+  2769   757  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+  2770   757  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
michael   2784  2695  0 13:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto gitlab
[michael@vps~]$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a simple solution you could use `yum history` command. After you could run `yum history undo <ID>` and it will revert all changes done in requested ID. If you do it just now, you could undo latest ID.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way to undo installation is that run `yum remove` on every thing before that installed with `yum install`. In this case run `sudo gitlab-ctl stop` and then `sudo yum remove gitlab-ee`.

Comment: The package he originally installed was `gitlab-ee` so that is the package he should remove. He tried removing a different package name and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a VPS. Destroy it, rebuild another VM if desired.

Studying the package management of an appliance and cleaning it up may be educational, but time consuming. Some appliances are only concerned about their one application and will leave configuration unmanaged by their packages.

Comment: Thanks John,  That was my plan unless it was simple (which I didn't expect).  Well, I learned something.  Always make a snapshot when on uncharted waters!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "It is a VPS"?

Comment: I mean it is a virtual machine and easily destroyed and rebuilt pristine. Software should have a clean removal process, but sometimes killing the VM is faster.